# Ruby Array - highest integer

Tags: ruby, arrays, each

brand new to Ruby, and love it. Just playing around with the below code:

```
    public
    def highest 
      highest_number = 0
      each do |number|
        number = number.to_i
        highest_number = number if number > highest_number
        puts highest_number 
      end
    end


    array = %w{1 2 4 5 3 8 22 929 1000 2}
    array.highest
```

So at the moment the response I get is:

```
    1
    2
    4
    5
    5
    8
    22
    929
    1000
    1000
```

So it puts the array first, then the highest number from the array as well. However all I want it to is put the highest number only...

I have played around with this and can't figure it out! Sorry for such a newbie question

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you have the `puts` statement inside the `each` loop, so during every iteration it prints out what the highest number currently is. Try moving it outside the `each` loop so that you have this:

```
public

def highest
  highest_number = 0
  each do |number| 
    number = number.to_i
    highest_number = number if number > highest_number
  end
  puts highest_number
end

array = %w{1 2 4 5 3 8 22 929 1000 2}
array.highest
```

Which produces the desired output:

```
1000
```

Answer (score 5):

You could also save yourself some trouble by using [`max_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001507):

```
>> a = %w{1 2 4 5 3 8 22 929 1000 2}
=> ["1", "2", "4", "5", "3", "8", "22", "929", "1000", "2"]
>> m = a.max_by { |e| e.to_i }
=> "1000"
```

You could also use another version of `max_by`:

```
m = a.max_by(&:to_i)
```

to avoid the extra noise of the "block that just calls a method".

But this is probably a Ruby blocks learning exercise for you so using existing parts of the standard libraries doesn't count. OTOH, it is good to know what's in the standard libraries so punting to `max_by` or [`max`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001504) would also count as a learning exercise.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this instead and avoid the `highest_number` variable.

```
array = %w{1 2 4 5 3 8 22 929 1000 2}

class Array
  def highest
    collect { |x| x.to_i }. \
    sort.                   \
    last.to_i
  end
end

array.highest # 1000
```

The `collect { |x| x.to_i }` can also be written as `collect(&:to_i)` in this case.